# What's the exact margin size separating two side by side minipage environments?

Tags: margins, minipage

Consider the following MWE with two `minipage` environments, ideally filling `1\textwidth` in total.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc,parskip,framed}
\usepackage[text={9in,6in},showframe,landscape]{geometry}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{minipage}[b][][b]{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{framed}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[b][][s]{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{framed}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}
%
\end{document}
```

With the following output

[image]

I guess the answer is simple, but what is the exact size of the margin between the `minipage`s? `0.8\textwidth`+`0.2\textwidth` > `1\textwidth` by `1.97156pt`.

Comment: In this case there's a normal interword space, caused by the end-of-line after the first `\end{minipage}`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. `%` at end of the first `minipage` solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not different from

```
a
%
b
```

that will have a space between `a` and `b`. Just mask off the end-of-line after the first `\end{minipage}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{framed}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{framed}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I've removed the inessential bits.

There's no space around a `minipage`, which will be as wide as the stated width.